# ArmorStand Passenger on Squid sinks away from Squid

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need some help! I am using the command:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {SpawnData:{id:"Squid",Passengers:[{id:"ArmorStand",Invulnerable:1,NoBasePlate:1,NoGravity:1}]},SpawnCount:1,SpawnRange:10,RequiredPlayerRange:20,Delay:5,MinSpawnDelay:30,MaxSpawnDelay:50,MaxNearbyEntities:20}
```

But when the armor stand hits water, it sinks away from the squid. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you tell us what you need this for? there may be other ways around this.

Comment: you may need to disable the armor stand's gravity setting. {NoGravity:1}

Comment: `{NoGravity}`is a binary byte data tag, and this one is one I know needs inputs kike`1b}` or `0b}`, so this is why it sinks.